# Unwanted reset of text form fields when hiting command button (save, print or send)

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a problem. I succeeded to make a document with a form filled by the user and a control board with few buttons to send, print or save the document when automaticcaly modified by the userform.

My problem is that for an unknown reason, when hitting one of those (print, save or send) button, the text form fields are reseting to default values.

Do you have any idea why ?

(I'm adding all the code below cause I've got no idea where is the problem coming from)

I tried deleting all the code step by step to find what was making that but it didn't give any explanation. I try remaking the document but I get the same trouble.

```
MENU_FORM : 

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

Dim AppXPoint, AppYPoint As Long    
AppXPoint = Application.Left + (Application.Width - Me.Width)    
AppYPoint = Application.Top    
With Me    
.StartUpPosition = 0    
.Left = AppXPoint - 200    
.Top = AppYPoint + 250    
End With  

End Sub    


Private Sub OUVRIR_FORMULAIRE_BOUTON_Click() 



MENU_FORM.Hide    
Load FORMULAIRE_FORM    
FORMULAIRE_FORM.Show   

End Sub    


Private Sub IMPRIMER_BOUTON_Click() 

ActiveDocument.PrintOut Copies:=1  

End Sub    


Private Sub QUITTER_BOUTON_Click()    

ActiveDocument.Saved = True    
Application.Quit  

End Sub    


Sub ENREGISTRER_BOUTON_Click() 

    Dim strNewFolderName As String    
    strNewFolderName = "DÉLÉGATION DE POUVOIRS POUR DÉPÔT DE PLAINTE - " & 
UCase(FORMULAIRE_FORM.DELEGATAIRE_PRENOM_TEXT) & " " & UCase(FORMULAIRE_FORM.DELEGATAIRE_NOM_TEXT)    
    If Len(Dir("S:\EDS-02450\JURIDIQUE\5 - CONTENTIEUX\3 - PÉNAL\" & strNewFolderName, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then    
        MkDir ("S:\EDS-02450\JURIDIQUE\5 - CONTENTIEUX\3 - PÉNAL\" & strNewFolderName)    
    End If    
    Dim PathName As String    
    PathName = "DÉLÉGATION DE POUVOIRS POUR DÉPÔT DE PLAINTE - " & UCase(FORMULAIRE_FORM.DELEGATAIRE_PRENOM_TEXT) & " " & UCase(FORMULAIRE_FORM.DELEGATAIRE_NOM_TEXT)    
    ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:="S:\EDS-02450\JURIDIQUE\5 - CONTENTIEUX\3 - PÉNAL\" & strNewFolderName & "\" & PathName & ".pdf", _
    FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF    
    MsgBox "Le fichier a bien été enregistré sous S:\EDS-02450\JURIDIQUE\5 - CONTENTIEUX\3 - PÉNAL\" & strNewFolderName  

End Sub    


Sub ENVOYER_BOUTON_Click() 

Dim strNewFolderName As String    
    strNewFolderName = "DÉLÉGATION DE POUVOIRS POUR DÉPÔT DE PLAINTE - " & UCase(FORMULAIRE_FORM.DELEGATAIRE_PRENOM_TEXT) & " " & UCase(FORMULAIRE_FORM.DELEGATAIRE_NOM_TEXT)    
    If Len(Dir("S:\EDS-02450\JURIDIQUE\5 - CONTENTIEUX\3 - PÉNAL\" & strNewFolderName, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then    
        MkDir ("S:\EDS-02450\JURIDIQUE\5 - CONTENTIEUX\3 - PÉNAL\" & strNewFolderName)    
    End If    
    Dim PathName As String    
    PathName = "DÉLÉGATION DE POUVOIRS POUR DÉPÔT DE PLAINTE - " & UCase(FORMULAIRE_FORM.DELEGATAIRE_PRENOM_TEXT) & " " & UCase(FORMULAIRE_FORM.DELEGATAIRE_NOM_TEXT)    

    ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:="S:\EDS-02450\JURIDIQUE\5 - CONTENTIEUX\3 - PÉNAL\" & strNewFolderName & "\" & PathName & ".pdf", _
    FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF    

Dim fichier    
fichier = "S:\EDS-02450\JURIDIQUE\5 - CONTENTIEUX\3 - PÉNAL\" & strNewFolderName & "\" & PathName & ".pdf"    
Dim adresse    
adresse = FORMULAIRE_FORM.DELEGATAIRE_PRENOM_TEXT & "." & FORMULAIRE_FORM.DELEGATAIRE_NOM_TEXT & "@azerty.fr"    
Outlook:  Set myApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")    
Set myItem = myApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)    
myItem.Subject = strNewFolderName    
myItem.Body = "Bonjour " & UCase(Left(FORMULAIRE_FORM.DELEGATAIRE_PRENOM_TEXT, 1)) & LCase(Mid(FORMULAIRE_FORM.DELEGATAIRE_PRENOM_TEXT, 2, 9 ^ 9)) & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Je vous prie de trouver en pièce jointe une délégation de pouvoirs à l'effet de déposer plainte pour les faits rapportés." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Bonne journée," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Service Juridique"    
myItem.Attachments.Add fichier    
myItem.to = adresse    
If adresse = "" Then     
Exit Sub    
End If    
myItem.Display    
myItem.Send    
MsgBox "Le courriel a bien été envoyé à " & UCase(Left(FORMULAIRE_FORM.DELEGATAIRE_PRENOM_TEXT, 1)) & LCase(Mid(FORMULAIRE_FORM.DELEGATAIRE_PRENOM_TEXT, 2, 9 ^ 9)) & " " & UCase(FORMULAIRE_FORM.DELEGATAIRE_NOM_TEXT) & " et le fichier a bien été enregistré sous S:\EDS-02450\JURIDIQUE\5 - CONTENTIEUX\3 - PÉNAL\" & strNewFolderName   

End Sub    





FORMULAIRE_FORM :


Private Sub UserForm_Activate()    

Dim AppXPoint, AppYPoint As Long    
AppXPoint = Application.Left + (Application.Width - Me.Width)    
AppYPoint = Application.Top    
With Me    
.StartUpPosition = 0    
.Left = AppXPoint - 200    
.Top = AppYPoint + 250    
End With    

End Sub    


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()    


   DELEGATAIRE_CIVILITE_BOX.AddItem "Monsieur"    
   DELEGATAIRE_CIVILITE_BOX.AddItem "Madame"    
   DELEGATAIRE_FONCTION_BOX.AddItem "Directeur de secteur"    
   DELEGATAIRE_FONCTION_BOX.AddItem "Directeur d'agence"    
   DELEGATAIRE_FONCTION_BOX.AddItem "Adjoint au directeur d'agence"    
   AUTEUR_BOX.AddItem "X"    
   AUTEUR_BOX.AddItem "1 personne déterminée"     
   AUTEUR_BOX.AddItem "2 personnes déterminées"    
   FAITS_BOX.AddItem "Escroquerie"     
   FAITS_BOX.AddItem "Usurpation d'identité"    
   FAITS_BOX.AddItem "Faux et usage de faux"    
   FAITS_BOX.AddItem "Vol"    
   FAITS_BOX.AddItem "Dégradation des biens de l'agence"     
   FAITS_BOX.AddItem "Abus de faiblesse"     
   FAITS_BOX.AddItem "Abus de confiance"    
   FAITS_BOX.AddItem "Diffamation"    
   FAITS_BOX.AddItem "Atteinte à l'honneur"    
   FAITS_BOX.AddItem "Menaces"    
   FAITS_BOX.AddItem "Injures"    

End Sub    



Private Sub AUTEUR_BOX_Change()    
If AUTEUR_BOX = "1 personne déterminée" Then    
FORMULAIRE_FORM.Hide    
Load AUTEUR_FORM    
AUTEUR_FORM.Show    

ElseIf AUTEUR_BOX = "2 personnes déterminées" Then    
FORMULAIRE_FORM.Hide    
Load AUTEURS_FORM    
AUTEURS_FORM.Show    
Else:    
End If    

End Sub    


Private Sub OK_BOUTON_Click()    

Dim A As String 'Civilité délégataire    
Dim B As String 'Prénom délégataire    
Dim C As String 'NOM délégataire    
Dim D As String 'Fonction délégataire    
Dim E As String 'Lieu des fonctions du délégataire    
Dim F As String 'Auteur    
Dim G As String 'Faits    
Dim H As String 'Date    

A = DELEGATAIRE_CIVILITE_BOX   
If DELEGATAIRE_CIVILITE_BOX <> "Monsieur" And DELEGATAIRE_CIVILITE_BOX <> "Madame" Then    
 MsgBox "Veuillez renseigner la civilité du délégataire", vbExclamation, "Erreur"    
 Exit Sub    
End If    
If DELEGATAIRE_CIVILITE_BOX = "" Then    
 MsgBox "Veuillez renseigner la civilité du délégataire", vbExclamation, "Erreur"    
 Exit Sub    
End If    
B = UCase(Left(DELEGATAIRE_PRENOM_TEXT, 1)) & LCase(Mid(DELEGATAIRE_PRENOM_TEXT, 2, 9 ^ 9))
If DELEGATAIRE_PRENOM_TEXT = "Prénom" Or DELEGATAIRE_PRENOM_TEXT = "" Then    
 MsgBox "Veuillez renseigner le prénom du délégataire", vbExclamation, "Erreur"    
 Exit Sub     
End If    
C = UCase(DELEGATAIRE_NOM_TEXT)    
If DELEGATAIRE_NOM_TEXT = "NOM" Or DELEGATAIRE_NOM_TEXT = "" Then    
 MsgBox "Veuillez renseigner le nom du délégataire", vbExclamation, "Erreur"    
 Exit Sub    
End If    
If DELEGATAIRE_FONCTION_BOX = "directeur d'agence" Then    
D = "Directeur de l'agence"    
ElseIf DELEGATAIRE_FONCTION_BOX = "Adjoint au directeur d'agence" Then    
D = "adjoint au directeur de l'agence"    
ElseIf DELEGATAIRE_FONCTION_BOX = "Directeur de secteur" Then    
D = "directeur du secteur"    
Else
D = DELEGATAIRE_FONCTION_BOX    
End If    
If DELEGATAIRE_FONCTION_BOX = "Fonction" Or DELEGATAIRE_FONCTION_BOX = "" Then
 MsgBox "Veuillez renseigner la fonction du délégataire", vbExclamation, "Erreur"    
 Exit Sub    
End If    
E = DELEGATAIRE_LIEU_TEXT    
If DELEGATAIRE_LIEU_TEXT = "Nom de l'agence ou du secteur" Or DELEGATAIRE_LIEU_TEXT = "" Then    
 MsgBox "Veuillez renseigner la zone d'exercice des fonctions du délégataire", vbExclamation, "Erreur"    
 Exit Sub    
End If    
If AUTEUR_BOX = "1 personne déterminée" Then    
F = UCase(Left(AUTEUR_FORM.PRENOM_TEXT, 1)) & LCase(Mid(AUTEUR_FORM.PRENOM_TEXT, 2, 9 ^ 9)) + "" + UCase(AUTEUR_FORM.NOM_TEXT)    
ElseIf AUTEUR_BOX = "2 personnes déterminées" Then    
F = UCase(Left(AUTEURS_FORM.AUTEUR1_PRENOM_TEXT, 1)) & LCase(Mid(AUTEURS_FORM.AUTEUR1_PRENOM_TEXT, 2, 9 ^ 9)) + " " + UCase(AUTEURS_FORM.AUTEUR1_NOM_TEXT) + " " + "et" + " " + UCase(Left(AUTEURS_FORM.AUTEUR2_PRENOM_TEXT, 1)) & LCase(Mid(AUTEURS_FORM.AUTEUR2_PRENOM_TEXT, 2, 9 ^ 9)) + " " + UCase(AUTEURS_FORM.AUTEUR2_NOM_TEXT)    
Else: F = UCase(AUTEUR_BOX)    
End If    
If AUTEUR_BOX = "Auteur" Or AUTEUR_BOX = "" Then    
 MsgBox "Veuillez renseigner le(s) auteur(s) des faits", vbExclamation, "Erreur"    
 Exit Sub    
End If    
If FAITS_BOX = "Escroquerie" Then    
G = "pour escroquerie"    
ElseIf FAITS_BOX = "Usurpation d'identité" Then    
G = "pour usurpation d'identité"    
ElseIf FAITS_BOX = "Faux et usage de faux" Then    
G = "pour faux et usage de faux"    
ElseIf FAITS_BOX = "Vol" Then    
G = "pour vol"    
ElseIf FAITS_BOX = "Dégradation des biens de l'agence" Then    
G = "pour dégradation des biens de l'agence"    
ElseIf FAITS_BOX = "Abus de faiblesse" Then    
G = "pour abus de faiblesse"    
ElseIf FAITS_BOX = "Abus de confiance" Then    
G = "pour abus de confiance"    
ElseIf FAITS_BOX = "Diffamation" Then    
G = "pour diffamation"    
ElseIf FAITS_BOX = "Atteinte à l'honneur" Then    
G = "pour atteinte à l'honneur"    
ElseIf FAITS_BOX = "Menaces" Then    
G = "suite à des menaces"    
ElseIf FAITS_BOX = "Injures" Then    
G = "suite à des injures"    
Else    
G = FAITS_BOX    
End If    
If FAITS_BOX = "Faits" Or FAITS_BOX = "" Then    
 MsgBox "Veuillez renseigner les faits", vbExclamation, "Erreur"    
 Exit Sub    
End If    

H = Format(Date, "dd mmmm yyyy")    

ActiveDocument.FormFields("A").Result = A    
ActiveDocument.FormFields("B").Result = B    
ActiveDocument.FormFields("C").Result = C    
ActiveDocument.FormFields("D").Result = D    
ActiveDocument.FormFields("E").Result = E    
ActiveDocument.FormFields("F").Result = F    
ActiveDocument.FormFields("G").Result = G    
ActiveDocument.FormFields("H").Result = H    

FORMULAIRE_FORM.Hide    
MENU_FORM.Show   

End Sub    

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)    

If CloseMode = 0 Then    
Unload FORMULAIRE_FORM    
FORMULAIRE_FORM.Hide    
Load MENU_FORM    
MENU_FORM.Show    
End If    

End Sub    


Private Sub ANNULER_BOUTON_Click()    
A = "civilité"    
B = "prénom du délégataire"    
C = "nom du délégataire"    
D = "fonction du délégataire"    
E = "lieu d'exercice des fonctions du délégataire"    
F = "auteur(s)"    
G = "pour les faits"    
H = "date"    


ActiveDocument.FormFields("A").Result = A    
ActiveDocument.FormFields("B").Result = B    
ActiveDocument.FormFields("C").Result = C    
ActiveDocument.FormFields("D").Result = D    
ActiveDocument.FormFields("E").Result = E     
ActiveDocument.FormFields("F").Result = F    
ActiveDocument.FormFields("G").Result = G     
ActiveDocument.FormFields("H").Result = H     

Unload FORMULAIRE_FORM    
Unload AUTEUR_FORM    
Unload AUTEURS_FORM    
FORMULAIRE_FORM.Hide    
Load MENU_FORM    
MENU_FORM.Show    


End Sub
```

Comment: We generally need the code to be able to help, yes.  But...we also need you to put in some more effort to narrow down where the issue might be caused.  It's hard for us to help when you just give us all of it; it's like trying to find a needle in a haystack.

Comment: I understand perfectly. But as I said , I don't have any idea where it's coming from. In my opinion, it should not happen. I tried to delete part by part every part of the code and I get the same trouble.

Comment: So you delete all your code, and it still happens?  That means it's not your code.

Comment: I believe it could be something else but I don't know what setting could do that. I made few weeks ago the same kind of document and it does not make this trouble, and word is not set differently.

Comment: This is why some additional debugging effort is required from your end; you need to narrow down where the error is coming from.  If you remove all your code, and it still happens, then it's not the code.  If it stops happening, it is the code, and you can use the built-in debugger to step through your code to see what's happening.

Comment: I'm quite trying for days to find where it is coming from. I pretty much know that it looks like a needle in a haystack but I did everything I could. If you don't want to help, that's your choice so don't waste your time.

Comment: Is the document protected as a form? If not, then any action that updates fields in the document will reset the form fields. If the document is protected as a form, does the code unprotect? andthen does it reprotect?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're using formfields in a document that doesn't have 'filling in forms' protection applied. You can apply that protection to the document before your code does anything with it (e.g. apply it manually to whatever template or document you're using), or you could use code like:

```
ActiveDocument.Protect Type:=wdAllowOnlyFormFields, NoReSet:=True
```

and run that upon opening or before printing, saving or sending.